# Downgrade SQL Server binaries BYOL on azure vm

Tags: sql-server, azure

VM was created with SQL Server BYOL 2016, however I want a VM with SQL Server BYOL 2012.

What needs to be done on the existing VM to remove 2016 binaries and install/add SQL Server 2012?

Comment: You need to **uninstall** SQL Server 2016, and then install SQL Server 2012.

Comment: how to do add  sql 2012 on existing vm

Comment: just create a new vm with sql 2012?

Comment: that is last option is there any other option to add sqlbinaries on existing VM